# Is it possible to programmatically create Custom SQL Tableau extracts that can be published and then refreshed on the server?

Tags: tableau-api, extract

Given some *Custom SQL*, I want to create a Tableau Extract programmatically.

Is this possible?

Context of the process is:

1. Generate SQL scripts for each extract (100+)
2. Create the (100+) extracts from Step 1
3. Publish the Extracts to Tableau Online
4. Refresh them there on a schedule

Step 2 can be done manually using Tableau Desktop's `Custom SQL`.
As seen here in this help doc, https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/customsql.htm

I want to do it (Step 2) programmatically, due to the number of extracts needed and the time it will take.

Comment: Apologies if I'm wrong on stack exchange for this.

Comment: It should work fine, which bit is not working ? As in what errors are you getting ?

Comment: No error, I've updated the question to help describe the problem

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can programmatically create extracts with the [Hyper API](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/hyper_api/en-us/index.html). Then you have the option to use either [Tabcmd](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd.htm), [Tableau REST API](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api.htm) or [Tableau Server Client Python](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/) library to publish the extract. If you go with Python to create the extract, then in the same script, you could use the Server Client to publish. Instead of tableau server refreshing it, you would schedule your script with some sort task scheduler, like in Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: You can use https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref_data_sources.htm#update_data_source_now to refresh the extract via Python as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Tableau can do Step 4, you just need to configure it.

Is the problem with steps 1-3 that you have the SQL and just need to automate that part ?

Comment: Please use your commenting privilege to ask clarification questions before answering.